# Meaning of "Look at me still talking when there's science to do"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

It's a famous video game song.
I really can't break it down to normal sense (being non-native). Also, I feel it's slightly glitched grammar.
Anyway, what does it mean?

Comment: It means, roughly, "I'm being foolish because I continue to talk when I should be working on a scientific task."

Comment: That could have been an answer. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the speaker is saying they are wasting time talking

> Look at me still talking

when there is *something else* that needs to be done

> when there's science to do.

Consider

> Look at us complaining we are hungry when we should just find a place to eat.